# Remove action name from Url in cakephp?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove action name from url in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069601/how-to-remove-action-name-from-url-in-cakephp)

I am using cakephp to develop my website in Cakephp and I would like to remove action(or view )name from the application URL what should I do fro that. 
My requirement is I want to add the parameters in place of view name recently my URL is like:

> "domainname/controllername/viewname/param1/param2"

but I need

> "Domainname/controllername/param1/param2"

My .htaccess files are like below

.htaccess in root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteRule    ^$     [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in app folder

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /liberty_new/app/
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/index.php/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/index.php/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

.htaccess in webroot folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine ON
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this in your `Config\routes.php` file.  Set the `Router` params to write the URL as you need.  Do not edit your htaccess files or it can/will break CakePHP routing.

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:param1/:param2', array('action' => 'index'), array('param1' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+', 'param2' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
```

This should send all requestes to any controller to the index function of that controller and pass params 1 and 2.  Of course, this can be heavily customized.  I would strongly suggest you read about routing in the documentation and never alter htaccess unless you have to.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

Comment: do i need to remove

    router::connect('/',array('controller'=>'page','action'=>'display'));

router::connect('/page/*',array('controller'=>'page','action'=>'display'));
form router.php

Comment: Not sure what you are asking in "do I need to remove", but read the documentation.  It explains exactly how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: do i need to remove

    router::connect('/',array('controller'=>'page','action'=>'display'));

router::connect('/page/*',array('controller'=>'page','action'=>'display'));
form router.php

Comment: If you use the pages controller and you don't want the application to use those routes, then yes.  You can setup an infinite number of routing rules.  CakePHP will use the URL route that it first matches, so if you used my rule and the pages rules you listed, and the url was /pages/test/test, then it would use the pages route.