# how to remove action name from URL in cakephp2

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

may be duplicate but I don't get any proper answer or help

actually I want to do like:

my current URL is : http://mysite.com/MyController/view/page1

but I want something like :http://mysite.com/MyController/page1

means I want to hide action name from URL.

I have used

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:id',array('action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

but its not working for me

below one working fine but

```
Router::connect('/:controller/*', array('action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

it applies for all controller but I wanted to apply for specific controller

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: thanks mark for ref. but I dont get any idea how to do this so please can you help me

Comment: I have used Router::connect('/:controller/:id',array('action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+')); but its not working for me

Comment: Is it really worth the trouble and time to make this minor adjustment? I bet there are bigger fish to fry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Router::connect('/MyController/:id', array('controller' => 'MyController','action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cake's routing to get this to work.

Add the following to your app/Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/Controller/page1', '/Controller/view/page1');
```

But you will have to add a route for every 'page'.

You can use a wildcard route to match everything starting with /Controller/:

```
Router::connect('/Controller/*', '/Controller/view/');
```

Or, without touching routes:

```
class FooController extends AppController

    public function index($stub) {

        $data = $this->findByStub($stub);

        if (!$data) {
            die('page not found');
        }

        $this->set('data', $data);

    }

}
```

}

Which allows you to have urls such as /foo/page1

(The routine looks for a Foo with a stub field matching 'page1')

This works, but you will loose the benefit of reverse routing which means you can make links like this: $this->Html->link(array('controller'=>'foo', 'action'=>'view', 'page1'); which cake will automagically rewrite to produce: /foo/page1

Comment: sorry buddy its not working for me or either am doing something wrong,I put you index function to my controller but its giving me error like page1 function not found in cotroller

Comment: How about this link..http://stackoverflow.com/a/14070172/576523.. i havent tried this.. but almost same problem here too...

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Router::connect('/:controller/*', array('action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Comment: but it applies for all controller but I wanted to aplly for specific controller

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your controller, Here am using GroupsController as an example

You add this in your app\Config\routes.php

```
Router::connect('/groups/:slugParam', array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index'), array('slugParam' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
```

This should redirect all requests of the form

http://www.site.com/groups/* to http://www.site.com/groups/index

( * => whatever comes after the controller name )

So now i have to alter my default index function in GroupsController to reflect this change

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class GroupsController extends AppController {

        public function index($id = null) {

            //pr($this->request->params);   this where all data is intercepted...
            if(isset($this->request->params['slugParam']) && !empty($this->request->params['slugParam'])) {

                // i have a slug field in groups databsae and hence instead of id am using slug field to identify the post.
                $data = $this->Group->findBySlug($this->request->params['slugParam']);
                $this->set('group', $data);
                $this->render('/groups/view');
            } 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: am getting one problem here if am using Router::connect('/groups/:slugParam', array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index'), array('slugParam' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
its not working for me but if i will use Router::connect('/groups/:id', array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index'), array('slugParam' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
thn its working

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Router::connect('/MyController/:id', array('controller' => 'MyController','action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```