# cakephp2 remove action name from URL

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

may be duplicate but I don't get any proper answer or help

actually I want to do like:

my current URL are:

1)http://mysite.com/MyController/index/page1

2)http://mysite.com/MyController/view/page2

3)http://mysite.com/MyController/display/page3

but I want something like :

1)http://mysite.com/MyController/page1

2)http://mysite.com/MyController/page2

3)http://mysite.com/MyController/page3

means I want to remove action name from URL but point page to that action

if we use

```
Router::connect('/:controller/*', array('action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

it will redirect all page to 'view' action but I want to redirect page to respective action

[how to remove action name from URL in cakephp2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805951/how-to-remove-action-name-from-url-in-cakephp2/17808700?noredirect=1#17808700)

Comment: mark that also my question but its not duplicate both's purpose are different

Answer (score 1):

Change `/:controller/*` to `/MyController/*` (so your specifying your controller, instead of making a global change).

Then change the action from view to index/display/whatever

Comment: but how to get which url for which action if i will enter url like:http://mysite.com/MyController/page3 it should point to display action and http://mysite.com/MyController/page2 it should point to view action

Comment: Instead of `MyController/*` use `/MyController/page3` The `*` at the end means ANYTHING after `MyController/` so instead of ANYTHING, you specify an exact string to match. (please note: i've never used cakephp, i worked all this out from the URL provided, so it cant be that hard to fathom)