# How to remove controller name and action name from URL in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I'm adding categories, products (along with category id) in admin panel and i want to show the products list category wise in the simple url as:

```
localhost/project_folder/[:category_name]
```

insted of

```
localhost/project_folder/HomeController/action/[:category_name]
```

and also i want to show the products deatils in the simple url as:

```
localhost/project_folder/[:product_id]
```

insted of

```
localhost/project_folder/HomeController/action/[:product_id]
```

I want to show all the details by using HomeController only.

By solution of [How to remove action name from url in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14069601/6448903), listing of products by category is working but product details are not working.

I got product list by `category_name` as below:

```
Router::connect
    '/:param',
    array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'category'), 
    array('pass' => array('param'))
);
```

But the details of product is not working if i used below one:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:param1',
    array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'details'),
    array('pass' => array('param1'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your router will get confused if you used this configuration (cause they are the same), you have to difference them by defining the nature of `param`

```
Router::connect('/:param', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'category'), array(
    'pass' => array('param'),
    'param' => '[a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z_0-9]*' // Accepts just words (category names slugged with _ caracter)
));
Router::connect('/:param1', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'details'), array(
    'pass' => array('param1'),
    'param1' => '[1-9]{1}[0-9]*' //Accepts just integers (product ids)
));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm sowing product details by product title. 
category contains only alphabets.
product title contains alphabets, - and numbers

Comment: got it by making changes like

Router::connect('/:param', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'category'), array(
    'pass' => array('param'),
    'param' => '[A-Za-z]*' // Accepts just words (category names slugged with _ caracter)
));
Router::connect('/:param1', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'details'), array(
    'pass' => array('param1'),
    'param1' => '[A-Za-z0-9-]*' //Accepts words and integers (product title)
));

Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, you got the idea :)

Comment: Router::connect('/:param', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'category'), array(
    'pass' => array('param'),
    'param' => '[a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z_0-9]*' // Accepts just words (category names slugged with _ caracter)
));    This lead to not accessing the other controllers like localhost/project_folder/LoginController

Comment: Yes, you are right, in fact i dont see other alternatives than adding a subroute to avoid this matter, like `Router::connect('/c/:param',` where `c` is the subroute